# PIE.htc filetype in Perforce

Tags: perforce, css3pie

The CSS3PIE `.htc` filetype in Perforce seems to cause issues when requesting the latest version. Changing the filetype from `Text` to `Binary` directly in Perforce fixed the problem.

Out of curiosity, does anyone have an idea why the `PIE.htc` format causes these problems? Could it be the encoding, the filetype, or attributes? If `PIE.htc` file type is set (as happens by default) to `text` in Perforce, it won't work when you try to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a '.htc' file is, but if you want all your '.htc' files to be treated as binary files by Perforce, rather than as text files, you can use the Perforce 'typemap' feature to do this: use 'p4 typemap'.

This blog: http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=79 has a nice writeup.

Generally, the reason you do this is that Perforce tries to normalize the line ending characters for text files, so that the files are a single line-end on Unix computers, but are carriage-return/line-end pairs on Windows computers.

And if your filetype contains 0x0a characters, but it is NOT a textual data type and these characters do NOT indicate line ends, then turning them into CRLF pairs will mess you up.

So then binary is the better filetype for such files.